# Fragment not attached to Activity in AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-fragments

Any idea why I'm having an illegal state exception with this code block?

```
mDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "OK",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    if (isAdded()) {
                        Intent viewIntent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                        startActivity(viewIntent);
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }
            });
```

Is it because I'm dismissing the dialog after starting a new activity?

Comment: You should paste your stack trace to add more info on the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
                    startActivity(viewIntent);
                    dialog.dismiss();

 replace with below 
           dialog.dismiss();
           startActivity(viewIntent);
```

**Is it because I'm dismissing the dialog after starting a new activity?**

**Ans : Yes**

> Well Activity and Dialog are different.Activity has a Dialog so 
>   without activity dialogs will not have any stand.(Only activity as has
>   control over UI not dialog).When you startNewactivity all activity
>   state is saved activity stack but stack cannot dialogs states since
>   its not part activity UI.(Dialog can exists only present activity
>   context). If any dialogs shown by any activity, before finishing or gettting saved to activity stack dialogs has to be removed from the UI.

Comment: so it's really the dismissing of the dialog after starting a new activity?

Comment: No.. U should dismiss dialog first den start new activity

Comment: actually what I meant to ask was, if it's really the dismissing of the dialog after starting a new activity that causes the problem. If so, can you explain why?

Comment: oh.. ok.. well as soon as u call "startNewActivity" that activity is basically state goes to "activitystack" and the underlying android operating system tries save its state (here state means ui or view contents). Dialog is also a ui component but only thing it has got to with  activity is whom should it get tied to is, always activity. And dialog can be live when activity has its state in ui(present on the screen).

Comment: Sorry but still don't get it. Do you know any blogs, docs, etc  that I can read regarding this topic?

Answer (score 0):

Just replace

```
  dialog.dismiss();
```

with

```
      mDialog.dismiss();
```